# incompatible types when assigning to type 'int *[]' from type 'int'

Tags: c, int

Criei um vetor de tamanho definido por uma constante, e ao chamar uma função que me retorna um vetor inteiro, este erro é gerado:

> incompatible types when assigning to type 'int *[]' from type 'int'

A assinatura da function é esta abaixo. O intuito é atribuir o retorno de um vetor a outro.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 50

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *V_VALORES_GERADOS[TAM];
    int *VETOR_ORDENADO[TAM];
    int *VETOR_VALORES[TAM];
    int *V_FREQ_SIMP_ABS[TAM];
    float *V_FREQ_SIMP_REL[TAM];
    int *V_FREQ_ACUM_ABS[TAM];
    float *V_FREQ_SIMP_ACUM[TAM];
    V_VALORES_GERADOS = Gerar_Vetor(6); //ERRO AQUI(PRIMEIRA INSTRUÇÃO DA MAIN)
}

int *Gerar_Vetor(int FATOR){    
    int x;
    int * VALORES = (int *) calloc (TAM, sizeof (int)); 

    //Gera os valores e os armazena em um vetor. 
    for (x = 1;x <= TAM; x++) {   
        VALORES[x] = rand() % FATOR + 1;
    }
    if (VALORES == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    else
        return VALORES;
}
```

Comment: Com  int *V_VALORES_GERADOS[TAM]; você está definindo um array de ponteiros para inteiros. É isto mesmo? Não seria um array de inteiros? Ou melhor apenas um ponteiro para o início da área alocada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com esta construção :

```c
int *V_VALORES_GERADOS[TAM];
```

você está dizendo que V_VALORES_GERADOS é um array de ponteiros para inteiros.
Sua rotina retorna um ponteiro para array de inteiros.

Veja as alterações que fiz em seu código:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int *Gerar_Vetor(int FATOR);
#define TAM 50

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int * P_V_VALORES_GERADOS = NULL;
    //inicializa semente 
    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );
    P_V_VALORES_GERADOS = Gerar_Vetor(6); //ERRO AQUI(PRIMEIRA INSTRUÇÃO DA MAIN)
    return 0;
}

int *Gerar_Vetor(int FATOR)
{    
    int x = 0;//sempre inicialize as variáveis
    int * VALORES = (int *) calloc (TAM, sizeof (int)); 
    //aqui você testa se a alocação teve êxito, pois se não fizer isto a execução seguinte pode causar erros em seu programa.
    //altera para printar na tela o motivo do erro.
    if (VALORES == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    //Gera os valores e os armazena em um vetor. 
    for (x = 1;x <= TAM; x++) 
    {   
        VALORES[x] = rand() % FATOR + 1;
    }
    return VALORES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A minha sugestão é de passar por parametro um array e coloca os dados nele.

```
void function(int *vetor){
     vetor = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
     vetor[0] = 1;
}
```